# Reuse pytest fixtures

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, fixtures

I am writing some tests using pytest many of which have similar fixtures. I want to put these "global" fixtures in a single file so that they can be reused across multiple test files. My first thought was to create a `fixtures.py` file such as

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture()
def my_fixture():
    # do something
```

Now how do I use this fixture in `my_tests.py`?

```
def test_connect(my_fixture):
    pass
```

This gives `fixture 'my_fixture' not found`. I can `from fixtures import my_fixture`. What is the suggested solution to this situation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pytest will share the fixtures in `conftest.py` automatically. Move the shared fixture from `fixtures.py` to `conftest.py`.

Comment: While this is probably a good idea to avoid lots of database connections, this does not address the issue in my question about how to import the fixture to the test file.

Comment: Note: you'll want to put these in *conftest.py* inside your tests directory — pytest will search for fixtures in *conftest.py*

Comment: Pytest does **not** share the fixture automatically in my current code. See the error message in my original question.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice you need to rename `fixtures.py` to `conftest.py` and add the `scope='session'` parameter.

Comment: The example database fixture is unimportant to my core question. I have edited your answer with the correct solution, which you mentioned in your last comment.

Comment: Also, FYI: if you ever want to restructure the fixtures out to `fixtures.py`, use `from fixtures import *` in your `conftest.py`. Be wary, though: `from xyz import *` will ignore anything whose name starts with an underscore, unless explicitly noted in `__all__`

Comment: Is there a way to do the above solution?? I mean instead of putting it in conftest can I put it in some other location??

Answer (score 0):

Fixtures located in a `conftest.py` file have vectical scoping with respect to the visibility of the fixture variable to test modules. This means that all test modules located as a sibling in the directory where the conftest.py file is located, or any subdirectories beneath that directory can all see the fixtures present in the conftest.py module.

That is a particular form of reuse but not always desired. If you want to reuse horizontally across test projects located in entirely different folders then you must put the fixtures within a "plugin module".

Take a look at these answers to get a sense of the possibilities

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/65247833/1330381
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/65348063/1330381