# Is there a way to configure pytest_plugins from a pytest.ini file?

Tags: pytest, ini

I may have missed this detail but I'm trying to see if I can control the set of plugins made available through the ini configuration itself.

I did not find that item enumerated in any of the [configurable command-line options](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#configuration-options) nor in any of the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#globalvar-pytest_plugins) around the `pytest_plugins` global.

The goal is to reuse a given test module with different fixture implementations.

Comment: `addopts = -p my.plugin.module.full.name -p my.other.plugin.module.full.name` should work, assuming the sys.path is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@hoefling is absolutely right, there is actually a pytest command line argument that can specify plugins to be used, which along with the `addopts` ini configuration can be used to select a set of plugin files, one per `-p` command.

As an example the following ini file selects three separate plugins, the plugins specified later in the list take precedence over those that came earlier.

`projX.ini`

```
addopts = 
    -p projX.plugins.plugin_1
    -p projX.plugins.plugin_2
    -p projY.plugins.plugin_1
```

We can then invoke this combination on a test module with a command like

```sh
python -m pytest projX -c projX.ini
```

A full experiment is detailed here in this repository
https://github.com/jxramos/pytest_behavior/tree/main/ini_plugin_selection