# Pytest: Run all tests in superclass

Tags: python, pytest

I want to run all the test methods inherited from another class. Is there a way to do so? For example, for the following code, I want `pytest` to test all the test methods of `TestTwo` and `TestTwelve` inherited from `Test`.

```py
class Test:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def test_even(self):
        assert self.n % 2 == 0

    def test_not_big(self):
        assert self.n < 100


class TestTwo(Test):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestTwo, self).__init__(2)


class TestTwelve(Test):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestTwelve, self).__init__(12)
```

However, `pytest` complains the existence of a `__init__` constructor. I want a way to circumvent this.

The overall goal is to make my tests more modular so that I can test similar problems on multiple classes.

Comment: Don't override `__init__` methods (here is a [statement from `pytest` dev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21440548/2650249)). What you are trying to implement is test parametrization; `pytest` offers an elegant way of parametrizing tests via decorators. Check out [Parametrizing fixtures and test functions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

The correct usage of `pytest` to reuse test methods is to use [Fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html). Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26266481/3383878) and an [example solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26370183/3383878).

Thank @hoefling for pointing out in the comment that `__init__` is bad for testing.